# Vote to Close, leaving annoying spelling error in Title

Tags: discussion

It may be the case that allowing a gross spelling errors uncorrected may provide clues to others as to just how poorly thought-out a question or answer is. But in [this case](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19956/masterbation-for-a-women-or-man-were-in-the-bible-is-it), having a PG-13 word left in poor spelling is just annoying.

Earlier we were asked not to edit Closed Questions. But in this case can someone correct it?

Comment: The notable exception to not editing a closed question is if you think you can make it in to a viable question that would be valid and unique.

Comment: Even though I was not aware of what *wax eagle* said in his answer, I didn't edit the title because I feel it, and the correlated question, disgusting. I think that, now that the question is closed, high-rep users should quickly delete it.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Why is the question disgusting? Though we are ill equipped to answer it on this site, would you posit that it does not deserve an answer anywhere? As a medium rep user I would not vote to delete it because it is a duplicate of a legitimate question.

Comment: @pterandon It's okay to just let it go. It will be off the home page in only a day or two more. Then I bet you will never see it again.

Comment: @fred., because it is against human nature and a capital sin.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider All right, [convince me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11110/for-elberich-and-fredsbend).

Comment: @fredsbend, I would really like to convince you, but I have no command of the English language to explain my though in reference to a so sensible subject. Thank you for your invitation, I appreciated a lot :)

Comment: @Elberich You sound like your English is just fine. It would be good practice.

Comment: Look, we're mostly all adults here, lets *act like it.* There's no reason to snicker like a 12 year old when the topic of sex comes up. We have a history of dealing with sticky topics related to sex with maturity. Let's keep it up. Sex (and other activities related to it) aren't disgusting, they're something that was created *by God* for us to enjoy. And keep in mind that we're from varying backgrounds, because *you* find something disgusting (or don't) doesn't mean someone else does (or doesn't). Even wrt what is and is not sin (which is why is x a sin is a banned topic in the general).

Answer (score 4):

Two times we don't want folks editing

- Very old, lousy closed questions. If you feel something needs cleanup, flag it and we'll probably just delete it.
- Spam/Offensive questions that need spam/offensive flags cast on them. The reason behind this is that editing will actually clear the spam/offensive flag.

If something doesn't meet one of these two criteria, please edit. If it's on the homepage and needs fixing, please edit it.